# Как убрать кавычки в значении переменной в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, переменные

Например, переменная `a` равна строке:
`a = 'Test'`.
Как сделать чтобы a стала равна этой же строке, но без кавычек? Чтобы `a` стала равна `Test`?
p.s. Просто нужно в ней хранить название функции, которое передаётся в строковом формате

Comment: Я даже с уточнением не понял в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

1. Открыть учебник по Python.
2. Прочитать раздел про строковые переменные. (Обычно не далее десятой страницы после начала книги).
3. Понять, что означает запись a = 'Test'.  (Собственно, вашей переменной a и присваивается текстовая строка без всяких кавычек).

P.S. Ума не приложу, как можно дойти до хранения названия функций и не знать, что такое строка?? Вы что  учебник читаете не подряд, а  одну страницу из каждых двадцати трех?

Comment: Вы немного не правильно поняли мой вопрос. Мне нужно потом название этой функции запустить(через exec), но`"Test"` не работает. но если я присваиваю этой переменной значение `Test`, и потом запускаю через exec, то всё работает (название функции `Test`)

Comment: Извините, не указал, что потом эту функцию нужно запустить

Answer (score 0):

Такой код вполне работает:

```py
def func(x):
    print(f'func({x}) call')

name = 'func'
arg = '10'
exec(f'{name}({arg})')

>>> func(10) call
```

Если же вы желаете с помощью `exec` присвоить переменной функцию по названию, то это будет как-то так:

```
def func(x):
    print(f'func({x}) call')

name = 'func'
var = 'a'
exec(f'{var} = {name}')
a(4)

>>> func(4) call
```